# Node should bounce when hitting scene edges

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm starting with SpriteKit. I want my spriteNote to bounce from the edges of the device. The problem is that I don't see any method, which would allow me to add edges.

```
// initWithSize:
_player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -1.0f);
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -1.0f);
}
```

I've tried to add something to `update` method, however the location looks strange (I have landscape mode only, `_player.position.y is` ~ 150px when I already don't see the player @.@ player graphic is 50x50px, node is `SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width / 2`).

Comment: I would suggest starting with your player in a visible location and update it slowly and log out the location as it moves to get a better understanding of what your coordinate system looks like.

Comment: This tutorial has a ball that bounces on edges: http://www.raywenderlich.com/49721/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-using-spritekit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add an edge around the screen for collisions in SpriteKit, you will need to attach a physicsBody to the scene.

In the `-initWithSize:` method, you need to add the following line:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

This will add a boundary around the scene which the balls can bounce off.

Comment: Fantastic! I've added physicsBody, but couldn't find this method with edges. That's exactly what I've been looking for!